# How to show Floating action sub menu?

Tags: android, material-design, floating-action-button, submenu, android-design-library

Is there a way to show the ["sub menu"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BHzxI.png) in a Android.Support.Design.Widget.FloatingActionButton?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: not with the official sdk. You have to rely on third-party  libraries or implement it by yourself

Comment: post your activity and xml sothat i can give you the full code for it

Comment: I dont have an xml, I just need to now if it a buildin feature or of I need to create my own sub menu

Comment: okay check my answer now

Comment: using FAB from support library you can't. But you can use for example this one [https://github.com/futuresimple/android-floating-action-button](https://github.com/futuresimple/android-floating-action-button)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the full implemented example
You can easily copy the classes and Paste to your packages with the res folder ..

[example](https://github.com/futuresimple/android-floating-action-button)

> Step 1 :- Add this to gradle

```
 compile 'com.getbase:floatingactionbutton:1.10.1'
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[FAB](https://github.com/Clans/FloatingActionButton)

A brilliant library which i currently use myself for fab along with a menu and animations and also handles ripples,plus it backports too so pre lollipop devices get all the features.